# Is it possible to ouput my data in JSON instead of XML in Oracle 11g

Tags: json, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I currently have an API built with PL/SQL that uses Oracle 11g. It currently outputs the data in XML. I have been tasked to convert this output to JSON. Is this even possible to do with Oracle 11g? I have been researching the web and I see that JSON support did not arrive until Oracle 12c. Is there a way I can convert the output of this API from XML to JSON. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the current XML output I have below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<items>
  -<CAGE_INFO>
       <CAGE_CODE>21356</CAGE_CODE>
       <ORG_NAME_ABBR>NASAJSC</ORG_NAME_ABBR>
       <ORGANIZATION_NAME>NASA/ LYNDON B JOHNSON SPACE CENTER</ORGANIZATION_NAME>
   </CAGE_INFO>
</items>
```

I need this JSON output using Oracle 11g:

```
{
"items": {
  "CAGE_INFO": {
     "CAGE_CODE": "21356",
     "ORG_NAME_ABBR": "NASAJSC",
     "ORGANIZATION_NAME": "NASA/ LYNDON B JOHNSON SPACE CENTER"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You might want to explore the PL/JSON package](https://github.com/pljson/pljson), which I believe has a module to convert XML to JSON.; though you might wan to generate JSON from your underlying data with it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "convert".

1. If you literally mean *convert* and are looking for a tool that takes arbitrary XML and returns JSON, well, writing that would be a lot of work. Someone may have done that already, I don't know.
2. If you just need this output in JSON, you could find wherever your XML is generated and rewrite it (I assume it's backed by one or more SQL queries) and call a PL/SQL package that generates JSON. My first stop would be [plsql-utils](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils) library and JSON_UTIL_PKG.
3. Or, take the function that generates your XML and rewrite it to construct JSON via string operations. JSON is just formatted text, after all. I've done this before and it might be the quickest way if your needs are simple.

Answer (score 0):

A direct conversion might be difficult. Instead you can use `XMLTYPE` to first parse the XML and then convert it to JSON. The conversion to JSON can be either a custom piece of code or if you have APEX installed on the DB instance, then you can look at the the `APEX_JSON` package.
Check this out for a description of `XMLTYPE` in Oracle.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm